# Как поделить тип данных Short на Byte?

Tags: java, типы-данных, приведение-типов

Почему в Java не получается поделить тип данных `short` на `byte` с последующим приведением результата к типу `short`? Почему не происходит автоматического перевода результата в `short`, он же больше `byte`?

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        short a = 250;
        byte b = 2;

        short c = (short) (a / b);
        // это работает, но почему нужно явно указывать (short)?

        // int c = a / b;
        // почему если переменную сделать типом int,
        // явно указывать тип не нужно?

        System.out.println(c);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ответ содержится в спецификации Java, [§5.6.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2). Для операций с двумя операндами (`*`, `/`, `+`, `-` и другие) типы меняются в следующем порядке:

- Если один из операндов типа `double`, второй конвертируется в `double`.
- Иначе, если один из операндов типа `float`, второй конвертируется в `float`.
- Иначе, если один из операндов типа `long`, второй конвертируется в `long`.
- Иначе, оба операнда конвертируются в `int`.

В вашем случае первый операнд имеет тип `short`, а второй — `byte`, поэтому они оба конвертируются в `int`.

Answer (score 0):

Всё просто. Результат a / b получается int. А большие типы автоматически не приводятся к меньшим.

Comment: Но ведь short>byte. Почему нужно явно указывать (short)
short c = (short)(a/b);
И почему если написать
 int c = a/b;  не нужно указывать (integer)?

Comment: Смотрите. (a / b) типа int. Представьве что в выражении `short c = (a / b)` вместо (a / b) будет переменная int: `int d = 5; short c = d;` разумеется int надо приводить в short. А в выражении `int c = (a / b)` (a / b) будет и так int'ом: `int d = 5; int c = d;` ну и int в int приводить не надо конечно же.